# Print pandas index in a pretty way

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn

```
print('Selected Features are {}'.format([X.columns[l1_rfe.get_support()]]))
```

gives

```
Selected Features are [Index([u'number_of_reviews', u'Occupations_art_culture_CSD',
   u'Occupations_natural_resources_CSD', u'Average_income_2005_CSD',
   u'Airport_id', u'Visitor_centre_id', u'City_Pop_2000',
   u'First_responder_id_ambulance', u'First_responder_id_fire',
   u'First_responder_lat_fire', u'events_10km', u'casinos_10km',
   u'transportation_10km', u'food_drinks_10km', u'boat_tours_10km'],
  dtype='object')]
```

Is there any way I can make this result prettier? `get_support` is from sklearn.feature_selection.RFECV if this is important to you.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a one approach using `get_values()`

To make the things reproducible, let's take this df:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(6,4),
                     index=list('abcdef'),
                     columns=list('ABCD'))

         A         B         C         D
a -0.168137  0.064138 -0.278186  0.069164
b  1.336853 -1.366735 -0.932872 -0.068140
c  0.986338 -0.253487 -2.069040 -0.017315
d -0.249902  0.597127 -0.079737 -1.128560
e -0.422776  1.497260 -0.774697 -0.593360
f  1.161005 -1.174774 -0.719904  0.634449
```

Printing:

```
In [20]: print('Features are: {}'.format([i for i in df1.index.get_values()]))
Features are: ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f']
```

Answer (score 0):

It all depends on what you mean by prettier, but if it was me, I would convert this index to a list, then to a string (converting right away to a string leaves "index metadata" to be suppressed, delete the brackets, unicode marks (using regexes) and quotes, and then format it in the way I please (maybe adding \n after each element). You may want to use pprint too.